# decorate on top of a click command

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, python-decorators, python-click

I am trying to decorate a function which is already decorated by `@click` and called from the command line.

Normal decoration to capitalise the input could look like this:

**standard_decoration.py**

```
def capitalise_input(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        args = (args[0].upper(),)
        f(*args)
    return wrapper

@capitalise_input
def print_something(name):
    print(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_something("Hello")
```

Then from the command line:

```
$ python standard_decoration.py
HELLO
```

The first example from the [click documentation](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) looks like this:

**hello.py**

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', prompt='Your name',
              help='The person to greet.')
def hello(count, name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for x in range(count):
        click.echo('Hello %s!' % name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

When run from the command line:

```
$ python hello.py --count=3
Your name: John
Hello John!
Hello John!
Hello John!
```

1. What is the correct way to apply a decorator which modifies the inputs to this click decorated function, eg make it upper-case just like the one above?
2. Once a function is decorated by click, would it be true to say that any positional arguments it has are transformed to keyword arguments? It seems that it matches things like `'--count'` with strings in the argument function and then the order in the decorated function no longer seems to matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that click passes keywords arguments. This should work. I think it needs to be the first decorator, i.e. it is called after all of the click methods are done.

```
def capitalise_input(f):
    def wrapper(**kwargs):
        kwargs['name'] = kwargs['name'].upper()
        f(**kwargs)
    return wrapper


@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', prompt='Your name',
              help='The person to greet.')
@capitalise_input
def hello(count, name):
    ....
```

You could also try something like this to be specific about which parameter to capitalize:

```
def capitalise_input(key):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper(**kwargs):
            kwargs[key] = kwargs[key].upper()
            f(**kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@capitalise_input('name')
def hello(count, name):
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested it, both work, is what I needed, especially the "which parameter" version.

Answer (score 10):

Harvey's answer won't work with command groups.  Effectively this would replace the 'hello' command with 'wrapper' which is not what we want.  Instead try something like:

```
from functools import wraps

def test_decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['name'] = kwargs['name'].upper()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: I am seeing the following error when I tried this with group:
```AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'command'```

Comment: In my case the command is converting to `<class 'function'>` even after using `@wraps`.

Answer (score 2):

About click command groups - we need to take into account what the documentation says - https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/commands/#decorating-commands

So in the end a simple decorator like this:

```
def sample_decorator(f):
    def run(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, param="yea", **kwargs)
    return run
```

needs to be converted to work with click:

```
from functools import update_wrapper

def sample_decorator(f):
    @click.pass_context
    def run(ctx, *args, **kwargs):
        return ctx.invoke(f, *args, param="yea", **kwargs)
    return update_wrapper(run, f)
```

(The documentation suggests using `ctx.invoke(f, ctx.obj,` but that has led to an error of 'duplicite arguments'.)